# Adding "Add Standard test" equivalent "Availability" event in Azure Application Insights from C# Console Application

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I am writing a C# console application to add "Add Standard test" equivalent "Availability" event in Azure Application Insights.
Here is code:

```
  
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();

        configuration.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=5xxx-xxx-xxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://usxxxxxx.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://usxxxxxx.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/";
        
        var client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        var counter = 0;
        while (counter < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Thread.Sleep(5000); 
                stopwatch.Stop();

                var success = true; // Set test Result success
                var durationMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                // Create AvailabilityTelemetry
                var availabilityTelemetry = new AvailabilityTelemetry
                {
                    Name = "AvailabilityTest",
                    Success = success,
                    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMs),
                    Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                    Message = "System is available",
                };

                // Send availability telemetry
                client.TrackAvailability(availabilityTelemetry);

                client.Flush();

                Console.WriteLine("Availability event sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                client.TrackException(ex);
                // Log error details
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }

            counter++;
        }
```

This code is generating metadata in the activity log.
[image]

But it is not creating any availability events.
When I click on the "Availability" menu under "Investigate" on the left panel of the Application insight, it can't find any availability data to show.

What I am missing here?

I tried to google any example, or tutorial, no luck.

Thanks in advance.
Ruhul

I tried to google any example, or tutorial, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the **`code`** (modified your code a little bit) which worked for me:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration rith_config = new TelemetryConfiguration();
        rith_config.InstrumentationKey = "5681d8dc-fe6a2";

        var rith_client = new TelemetryClient(rith_config);
        var rith_count = 0;

        while (rith_count < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                var rith_stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                rith_stopwatch.Stop();

                var rith_success = true; 
                var durationMs = rith_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                var rith_availabilityTelemetry = new AvailabilityTelemetry
                {
                    Name = "AvailabilityTest",
                    Success = rith_success,
                    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMs),
                    Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                    Message = "Testing availability logs",
                };
                rith_client.TrackAvailability(rith_availabilityTelemetry);
                rith_client.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Availability event sent successfully to Application Insights!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rith_client.TrackException(ex);
                Console.WriteLine($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, Error is : {ex.Message}");
            }

            rith_count++;
        }
        rith_client.Flush();
    }
}
```

You need to give just instrumentation key not the full connection string in my code and changed the flush and some other parts of code.

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]